# Resume installer after system restart caused by executed uninstaller of the previous version

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have a reasonably standard Inno Setup installer. When uninstall runs, a reboot is necessary, it deletes a service and unregisters a DLL. I have in place some code that detects an older version of the software (thanks stackoverflow). If the older version is detected and the user wants to install the newer version:

1. The uninstaller is invoked
2. The software is uninstalled
3. The system (correctly) reboots
4. The system starts up and I log back in

What should happen now (IMHO) is that the installer should continue where it left off, ie. installing the new version into the same folder as the old version. But it doesn't, nothing happens. I have read the help files, checked the switches (to the best of my limited ability) and asked Dr Google, but nothing.

**My question:** Is it possible to do this, ie. continue the install after a reboot and, if so, how?

Here's my (well much of the stackoverflow) code that works except that nothing continues when the system is reboot (If you need any of the other sections of the installer let me know):

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  oldVersion: String;
  uninstaller: String;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin

  if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppID}_is1') then
  begin
    RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppID}_is1', 'DisplayVersion', oldVersion);
    if (CompareVersion(oldVersion, '{#MyAppVersion}') < 0) then
    begin
      if MsgBox('Version ' + oldVersion + ' of EMPSecure is already installed. Continue to use this old version?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
      begin
        Result := False;
      end
      else
      begin
          RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppID}_is1', 'UninstallString', uninstaller);
          ShellExec('runas', uninstaller, '/SILENT', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
          if (ErrorCode <> 0) then
          begin
            MsgBox( 'Failed to uninstall EMPSecure version ' + oldVersion + '. Please restart Windows and run setup again.', mbError, MB_OK );
            Result := False;
          end
          else
          begin
            Result := True;
          end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      MsgBox('Version ' + oldVersion + ' of EMPsecure is already installed. This installer will exit.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the uninstaller invoked from installer restarts the system, the installer is aborted for good.

If you want to resume the installer after restart, you have to take care of it yourself.

For example you can add the installer itself to `RunOnce`:

```pascal
RegWriteStringValue(
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', 
  'ResumeMyInstaller', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'));
```

Comment: It almost works. However in my code '{srcexe}' is translated literally as a string and the value of the registry entry for ResumeMyInstaller is {srcexe} NOT the fully qualified path of the actual installer. If I remove the quotations I get a syntax error. Do you know how to actually get that value in PASCAL code?

Comment: Found out needed ExpandConstant('{srcexe}') to get the actual value of {srcexe}, I amended your code accordingly, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the answer.